# How can I get a user account back?

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

With all my computers I make one partition for the root and another for /home. This is useful for disasters where I need to reformat the root for ubuntu, but leave my /home data untouched.

With the upgrade to 13.10 I had troubles on my wife's computer so I reinstalled 13.10. My own /home files came up, as expected, as if nothing had happened. For my wife, it is a different story - and that is the part where I need help.

If I go into Files, computer I can see the home directory. There I can see ilan (my files) and yona (my wife's files). I can open yona, documents and see all her work. This means that all is well and I just need to hook up to her files.

So the problem is that I need to create a user called Yona or yona, but something which will get me to exactly the files of interest. I'm not sure if I created her account as standard or an administrator. Is there any way I could tell by looking at the files in /home?

I created a new user called Yona as a standard user (hoping that this is the right guess). The account came up as disabled. I pressed on the disabled button so I could change the password. I put in her password but it was refused as too short. Too short, too short, but that is what was used and that is what I need.

Can anyone help me before my wife comes home and shoots me?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a user with login *Yona* whereas it previously was *yona*, then you can correct this by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo usermod -l yona Yona
```

If yona logs in and doesn't get to her files, then you can subsequently set the correct home directory using:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/yona yona
```

To solve the issue with the password, open a terminal and type

```
sudo passwd yona
```

and you can set yona's password without the system complaining. Note that this may first ask for *your* password, then twice for Yona's new password, like this:

```
ilan@machine:~$ sudo passwd yona
[sudo] password for ilan:              # here enter your password
Enter new UNIX password:               # here enter her new password
Retype new UNIX password:              # here enter her new password again
```

If the files in Yona's home directory all seem to have a strange numeric owner, you'll need to change Yona's `uid` a/o `gid` to what it was on the old system, thusly:

```
sudo usermod --uid ### --gid ### yona
```

where you substitute the appropriate numbers at the ###.

Next time when restoring the system, I would recommend creating Yona's account not via the GUI, but using the `adduser` command, substituting the appropriate values:

```
adduser --home /home/yona --uid ### --gid ### yona
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not out of the woods yet. I've got a mess with user yona. Just to make sure things were OK I created a user kkk which I could then delete. this is what I have ilan@ilan-Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo deluser kkk
Removing user `kkk' ...
Warning: group `kkk' has no more members.
Done.
ilan@ilan-Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo deluser yona
Removing user `yona' ...
Warning: group `saned' has no more members.
userdel: group yona not removed because it is not the primary group of user yona.
Done.

Comment: Is there a nicer way to format these comments? My cut and paste is very ugly.

Comment: The problem is that the yona which I created using the terminal doesn't show up at log in. I've got to totally kill yona and then recreate her. All this without killing the files.

Comment: I had no idea what saned was so I looked in etc/password and I find colord:x:114:122:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
saned:x:115:123::/home/saned:/bin/false
ilan:x:1000:1000:ilan,,,:/home/ilan:/bin/bash As --uid I had picked a random value of 123 which I see in saned. Should my actual value be 1001?

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct even though in my case I managed to shoot myself in the foot with all the add and remove user attempts. When I finally got it to go I saw that it wouldn't fly, presumably because I had managed to damage /home/yona. So I renamed it to backy and created Yona with a new /home/yona. From there I needed only to mv /home/backy... /home/yona... (on each directory of interest).